# How to Recieve BufferedImage[] in android using SOAP? and How to show that BufferedImage[] images in imageview?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

How to Recieve `BufferedImage[]` in android using `SOAP`? and How to show that `BufferedImage[]` images in `imageview`?

My Class File Code :

```
SoapObject request2 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE2, METHOD_NAME2);        
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope2 = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope2.setOutputSoapObject(request2);
HttpTransportSE ht2 = new HttpTransportSE(URL2);
request2.addProperty("refDocno", "BDQA - 214");                 
ht2.call(SOAP_ACTION2, envelope2);
final SoapObject response2 = (SoapObject) envelope2.bodyIn;
```

---

Now How to use `response2 data` & how can I show images of that response in `imageview`?